# how to stop the GC in embedded mono from the native c code

Tags: mono, garbage-collection

I have two kinds of Software Developers, one focus on native `C` and the other focus on `.Net` or `mono`, and we develop some integrated software by embedded `mono`.  We did it by learning online and it seemed ok at the start.  But gradually, we meet bugs about memory corruption more and more often.  While it is costly to train them to be familiar with the other side and tons of interop stuff so that they won't contribute to a memory corruption integration software, as a  manager, I am thinking maybe it is cheaper to have the standard `C` code:

- step 1 stop `GC` thread before calling a mono,
- step 2 call `result = mono_runtime_invoke(..)`, and
- step 3 start `GC` thread after all treatment about result is done by the `C` code.

The memory corruption is very often that the `C` guy is doing something with a pointer pointed to the managed space while `GC` is freeing/moving the data.

How to achieve this and any comment ?

Comment: my advice would be: Fix the cause, not the symptoms...

Comment: the cause is "the pointers are being moved" so i would think stopping GC is also a "Fix"; after al, GC will restart to do its job, alone.

Answer (score 2):

The recommended practice is to create GCHandles to the managed object so that the GC knows about them instead of stopping the GC.

This is accomplished using the following functions:

```
mono_gchandle_new
mono_gchandle_new_weakref
mono_gchandle_get_target
mono_gchandle_free
```